# awk write each match to a file and increment filename

Tags: awk, certificates

I want to read a file without whitespaces, filled with root certificates and separate them into new files per match. I can select all matching certificates at once and insert to a single file, but I can't figure out how to separate per match and make print create a new file each cert.

```
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ { print > outputlist }' inputlist
```

I tried it already with a while read loop, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
awk '/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/,/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {
       if (/-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/) nb++
       print > "certificate" nb ".txt"
     }' inputlist
```

I always have this page open aside when writing `awk` script: [Awk](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Files generated:

```
$ ls certificate*
certificate1.txt  certificate2.txt
```